# Control the order of methods using JMH

Tags: java, jmh

I'm using JMH benchmark in my project.
I have method 1 and method 2 annotated with @Benchmark.
I want the order to be: method1, method2, mehod1, method2... and so on... 
Which means: I wand that method 2 will immediately follow method 1. Is there a way to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you get the same result regardless of order?

Comment: Well, method 2 needs to use an ArrayList built in method 1

Comment: Hello @TaliG, I'm wondering how to make sure the method 2 execute after the execution of method 1? I tried to implement this, but method 1 and 2 will execute asynchronously. In this situation I can't control the execution order.

Answer (score 6):

The order in which JMH executes `@Benchmark` methods is usually irrelevant: the runs are isolated from each other, and so results are independent. But in case you still want the particular order, then `@Benchmark`-s are executed in the lexicographical order, hence, rename your methods in that order.

Comment: This works (so thank you for the answer), but now my methods are called `_0_january()`, `_1_feburary()`, `_2_march()`, ... *That's ugly!* JMH should probably support `@Benchmark(reportOrder = 2) String march() {}` instead.

Comment: I agree with Geoffrey. It would be nice to control the benchmark execution/reporting order. In my case, I'd want `@Benchmark` methods to get executed in the order they are present in the class file. I have 2 use-cases: 1. I am profiling the code and I want to quickly control which method runs first so I can profile it. 2. The methods are related. I want to report benchmark numbers in an order that is more intuitive for readers. I'd prefer controlling this through method ordering than annotations because the parameters are error-prone (e.g. two annotations may have the same parameter value).