# How to run methods in benchmarks sequentially with JMH?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

In my scenario, the methods in benchmark should run sequentially in one thread and modify the state in order.

For example, there is a `List<Integer>` called `num` in the benchmark class. What I want is: first, run `add()` to append a number into the list. Then, run `remove()` to remove the number from the list.

The calling sequence must be `add() --> remove()`. If `remove()` runs before `add()` or they run concurrently, they would raise exceptions because there's no element in the list.

That is, `add()` and `remove()` must be called **sequentially** and in **one** thread.

In [Control the order of methods using JMH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261369/control-the-order-of-methods-using-jmh), I learned that the methods run in the lexicographical order. I tried the code below:

```java
@State(Scope.Group)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Fork(value = 10)
public class ListBenchmark {

    private List<Integer> num;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .verbosity(VerboseMode.NORMAL)
                .syncIterations(true)
                .threads(1)
                .include(".*" + ListBenchmark.class.getCanonicalName() + ".*")
                .build();

        new Runner(options).run();
    }

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        num = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    @Group("num")
    public void add() throws Exception {
        num.add(1);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    @Group("num")
    public void remove() throws Exception {
        num.remove(0);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, because the `add` method and the `remove` method run concurrently. In some cases, the `remove` runs before `add` and raises `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

How to run the methods in benchmarks sequentially with JMH?

Answer (score 1):

You start with a wrong precondition and everything fails short because of that. You can see a broader explanation from the authors [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_15_Asymmetric.java#L56). You want symmetry where asymmetry is implied.

If you want to see how much it takes `add -> remove` place them both in the same `@Benchmark`, and same for individual `add` or `remove` via different `State`. For example:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class BothAddAndRemove {

    List<Integer> num;

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        num = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class RemoveOnly {

    List<Integer> num;

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        num = new ArrayList<>();
        num.add(1);
    }
}


@Fork(25)
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
public int add(BothAddAndRemove both) {
    both.num.add(1);
    return both.num.remove(0);
}

@Fork(25)
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
public int removeOnly(RemoveOnly removeOnly) {
    return removeOnly.num.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I think what I want is the methods change the state one by one, not asynchronously. For example, first add one element into the list, and then remove that element. The execution should be carried out in one thread. By the way, I wonder what is the difference between return void and return int?

Comment: @Thesharing 1) about your examples, it might be me, but I simply don't understand your point. May be someone else will see this question and explain better 2) in the case of `int` vs `void`, for `SingleShot` this does not matter; but in general JVM can "see" that your method has no side-effects and simply decide not to do anything inside it. You might want to read on `Blackhole`s too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. I think it must be my description that is hard to understand... And it seems I need to read more articles about JMH. Thank you for your time.