# Cannot force the benchmark order in a JMH project

Tags: java, jmh

In my JMH project, I exhibit an order dependence: one benchmark must be run before another. I tried a lot of different configurations, but, alas, the benchmark order is invalid. The entire project lives [here](https://github.com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedListBenchmark).

My sample snippet follows:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class IndexedLinkedListPerformance {

    private static final int ADD_FIRST_OPERATIONS = 20_000;
    private static final int GET_OPERATIONS = 10_000;

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class IndexedLinkedListState {
        public List<Integer> list;
        public Random random;
        
        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void setup() {
            list = new IndexedLinkedList<>();
            random = new Random(seed);
        }
    }
 
    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 1)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @Fork(0)
    @Group(value = "g1")
    public void Benchmark_1A_profileAddFirstRoddeList(IndexedLinkedListState state) {
        profileAddFirst(state.list,
                        ADD_FIRST_OPERATIONS, 
                        state.random);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 1)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @Fork(0)
    @Group(value = "g1")
    public void Benchmark_1B_profileGetRoddeList(IndexedLinkedListState state,
                                                 Blackhole blackhole) {
        profileGet(state.list,
                   GET_OPERATIONS,
                   state.random, 
                   blackhole);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .forks(0)
                .warmupForks(0)
                .warmupIterations(1)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(2L))
                .measurementIterations(1)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(2L))
                .jvmArgsPrepend("-server", "-Xms7G", "-Xmx7G")
                .forks(1)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .syncIterations(true)
                .threads(1)
                .build();
        
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}
```

I have followed all the samples in [JMH samples](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/tree/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples), where I have tried some possibly relevant solutions, but they did not resolve my issue.

Comment: It sounds duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271493/5088764

Comment: @sbernard Not quite. I indeed need to preserve the order.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get something but I understand that benchmark are launch in lexical order. The full name (e.g : my.package.MyClass.myBenchMethod) is used for ordering. So if you want specific order (which seems strange needs) just rename your method (and/or package / class if needed)

Comment: @coderodde The proposed duplicate question asks how to control the order of the methods run by JMH, and the answer explains how. Your question _is_ a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @sbernard I tried the order by name -trick, but JMH kept on running in invalid order. However, I tried names like bench_1A, bench_1B. It turned out that I should have written benchA, benchB, etc. Looks like JMH doesn’t like underscores.

Comment: @coderodde Surprising !  I tested it on my side and even with underscore It seems It works for me 